# Uncountable Point exclusion topology: Arc connectedness

Tags: general-topology, connectedness

I am trying to prove some facts about the **uncountable point exclusion topology**: in particular I have some doubts about arc-connectedness.

Let $(\mathbb R,\tau)$ indicate the real line equipped with the topology
$$\tau:=\{A\subset \mathbb R : A \cap \{0\} = \varnothing \}\cup \mathbb R$$
$\tau$ is discrete on $\mathbb R\setminus \{0\}$: every subset $A$ of $\mathbb R \setminus \{0\}$ is such that $A\cap \{0\}=\varnothing$, so $A$ is open.

$(\mathbb R, \tau)$ is clearly connected: suppose by contradiction that there exists a nontrivial clopen set $A$. If $A$ is an open set, then $A\cap \{0\}=\varnothing$. If $A$ is closed, $A^C\cap \{0\}=\varnothing \iff A\cup (\mathbb R \setminus \{0\})=\mathbb R$ and $0 \in A$, a contradiction.

Now, I'd like to believe that the space is not arc-connected: this is claimed [here](https://topology.pi-base.org/spaces/S000013). On my topology course notes (in Italian, you can find them [here](http://www.math.unipd.it/%7Emaurizio/t1/GeoTopEle.pdf)) it is claimed on page $104$ that $\mathbb R$ with the point exclusion topology is arc-connected.

If we suppose that $(\mathbb R, \tau)$ is arc-connected, this would mean that for every $x_1, x_2 \in \mathbb R$ there exists a continuous function
$$\begin{array}{r c c c }\gamma: & [0,1]& \longrightarrow & \mathbb R\\
& t & \mapsto &\gamma(t)\end{array}$$
such that $\gamma(0)=x_1$, $\gamma(1)=x_2$; taking $x_1>0$, $x_2>0$, this would imply that every fiber $\gamma^{-1}(x)$ with $x\in (x_1,x_2)$ would be an open set; since $[0,1]$ is $T_1$, points are closed, but it is also connected so fibers must be either empty or at least intervals of the form $(a,b)$. This is kind of far-fetched but I cannot find an explicit contradiction.

Would a function like
$$\gamma(t)=\begin{cases} x_1 & t\in[0,\frac{1}{3}) \\ 0 & t\in[\frac{1}{3},\frac{2}{3}]\\x_2 & t \in(\frac{2}{3}, 1] \end{cases}$$
work? Let's say that $A$ is an open set in the codomain $(\mathbb R, \tau)$: then $0 \not \in A$.
Then

- If $A$ does not contain $x_1,x_2$, $\gamma^{-1}(A)=\varnothing$, which is open.
- If $A$ contains $x_1, x_2$ or both, then its preimage can be either $[0,\frac{1}{3})$, $(\frac{2}{3},1]$ or $[0,\frac{1}{3})\cup (\frac{2}{3},1]$ which are open sets in $[0,1]$ with the subset topology.

Is $(\mathbb R, \tau)$ an arc connected space or not? Can somebody point to a proof?

Comment: Add: I found out that different authors require invertibility for the path, so I guess this could be the issue. Choosing $x_1=0$, $x_2=x$: if $\gamma(0)=0$ and $\gamma(1)=x$, injectivity implies that $\gamma^{-1}(x)=\{1\}$; but $x$ is open because $\{ x\} \cap \{0\}=\varnothing$, while $\{1\}$ is closed in $[0,1]$, which is connected. QED

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The concept of [arc connected](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Arcwise-Connected.html) seems to be inconsistently defined in the literature: that link refers to two definitions.

In one definition, "arc connected" requires the path to be a homeomorphism onto its image, in which case the topology $\tau$ is not arc connected: there are no subspaces whatsoever that are homeomorphic to $[0,1]$, because any $t \in [0,1]$ which does not map to $0 \in \mathbb{R}$ would have to form a singleton open set $\{t\} \subset [0,1]$, which is absurd.

In the other definition, "arc connected" is a synonym for "[path connected](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Connected_space#Path_connectedness)", in which case the topology $\tau$ *is* arc connected, for instance if $x_1,x_2 \ne 0$ then they are connected by the path
$$\gamma(t) =
\begin{cases}
x_1 & \quad\text{if $t \in [0,1/2)$} \\
0 &\quad\text{if $t=1/2$} \\
x_2 &\quad\text{if $t \in (1/2,1]$}
\end{cases}
$$
whereas $x_1=0$, $x_2 \ne 0$ are connected by the the path
$$\gamma(t) =
\begin{cases}
0 &\quad\text{if $t=0$} \\
x_2   &\quad\text{if $0 < t \le 1$}
\end{cases}
$$
and similarly for $x_1 \ne 0$, $x_2 = 0$.

Comment: This clears it up. Thank you very much.

Comment: It is my pleasure.